# How to access C++ public bool class member in C file(to validate)?

Tags: c++, c

I am having static bool variable in c++ class
In **

- list.hh

**

```
   namespace U 
   {
    class list 
    {
     public:
     static bool mode;
    };
   }
```

In **

- list.cc

**
  The definition declared

```
namespace U 
{    
 bool list::mode = false;
}
```

Now I am going to access these boolean in boolc.c "C" file

In boolc.c

```
#include<U/list.hh>

   If( (U::list:mode) == true)
    return "enabled";
   else
    return "disabled";
```

I could not able to compile this file as it is saying "bool" is not supported in C. More over "list.hh" file not found error. How to correct these issue?

Comment: `bool` has support in C (`stdbool.h`). That's not your problem.

Comment: And don't forget to use C11 compiler command line option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

namespace and classes are unknown in C, you cannot compile a file containing including *list.hh* with a C compiler, compile all in C++

> ```
> #include<U/list.hh>
> ```
>
> More over "list.hh" file not found error

note normaly when we #include a user file it is given between "", but you just miss something like a -I option to allow the compiler/preprocessor to find the file, but again the main problem is not here

Comment: I added extern boolean variable and access it across the files.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to get the address of the U::list::mode variable and pass that to the C code. In the C++ code you would then do something like this:

```
  bool* ptr = &U::list::mode;
  some_c_function(ptr);
```

and in the C code implementing `some_c_function` you would then have access to the pointer so you could check the value of `U::list::mode` there, although in the C code you would not write `U::list::mode` but instead you would write something like `*ptr` which would refer to the same memory location so it would effectively be the same as `U::list::mode` allowing you to check that value from within your C code.